# php5 intl 1.1.2 LOCALE configuring / not working properly

Tags: php, locale, php-5.2, intl

I had a copy of PHP 5.2.17 (running on Debian) without intl extension installed on my server. I followed [*Howto: build and install the intl PECL extension for PHP5 in Debian*](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2008/07/howto_build_and_install_the_intl_pecl_extension_for_php5_in_debian/) guide and got it installed, however the Locale class is still not working properly.

- `Locale::DEFAULT_LOCALE;` is `NULL`.
- `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_US', 'fr_FR.UTF8', 'fr.UTF8', 'fr_FR.UTF-8', 'fr.UTF-8')` is `false`

If I setup  `ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'cs_CZ');` and call `Locale::DEFAULT_LOCALE;` on the next line then the result is `NULL` again.

PHPInfo is says:

```
intl.default_locale = no value
intl.error_level    = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing PHP 5.3 and updating list of available locales with locales-all package (thank you for that package!) solved the problem.

Comment: Did installing debian package php5-intl, uninstall other packages?